# Using $filter on List<String> Outlook calendar

Tags: exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api

I have been looking up OData protocol for [`$filter`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358) and trying to look up the syntax for filtering response from ms-graph based on categories eq 'FlexUser'.

in the response I get:

```
...,
"categories": [
                "FlexUser"
            ],
...
```

While trying to expand categories before using filter I get an error says that categories can't be expanded. Can anyone explain how to filter on List param?

I create the category when creating the event so that category does not exist in my outlook calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are fetching a list of [events](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) with e.g.

```
/v1.0/me/calendar/events
```

and want to filter all events which contain a specific category.
In this case you have to use the [any](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc444868731) operator in your [filter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter):

```
$filter=categories/any(c:c eq '@break')
```

So your request could look like this:

```
/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=categories/any(c:c eq 'FlexUser')
```